# Extract data from PHP Object

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the Facebook API and the class produces this object.

```
   object(User)#4 (5) {
      ["fbc_uid"]=>
      string(9) "324234324"
      ["fbc_first_name"]=>
      string(5) "James"
      ["fbc_last_name"]=>
      string(5) "Proud"
      ["fbc_name"]=>
      string(11) "James Proud"
      ["fbc_email"]=>
      NULL
    }
```

How do I extract the fbc_uid from this object, from outside the "User" Facebook class?

Comment: Could you be a little more precise what your exact problem is? Is the `fcb_uid` field private?

Comment: No I don't think so. I am just not sure how I access it. It is called as $facebook, but I can't access it like a normal array $facebook['fcb_uid..., how can I do that as it's as an object?

Comment: Then, as jake said, $facebook->fcb_uid is your friend :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$userObj->fbc_uid
```